# Is changing default virtual address in elf header to 0 possible?

Tags: linux, elf

Can I change the default virtual address(ph_vaddr)  in the elf to 0x0. will this allow access to null pointer?? or the kernel does not allow to load at address 0?

I just want to know that if I change the p_vaddr of some section say .text to 0x0, does linux allow this? Is there some constraint that virtual address can start only after some value? Whenever I was trying to set .text vaddr using ld --section-start anywhere between 0 to 9999 it was getting killed. I want to know what is going on??

Comment: Please explain **why do you ask** !!

Comment: I was reading elf format and then I started playing around with the p_vaddr to understand it better. At this point I was lost so I came here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can I change the default virtual address(ph_vaddr) in the elf to 0x0.

Yes, that is in fact how `PIE` (position independent) executables are usually linked.

```
echo "int main() { return 0; }" | gcc -xc - -fPIE -pie -o a.out
readelf -l a.out | grep LOAD | head -1

LOAD           0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
```

Note: above makes an executable that is of type `ET_DYN`.

> will this allow access to null pointer?

No. When the kernel discovers that the `.e_type == ET_DYN` for the executable, it will relocate all of its segments elsewhere.

You can also make an executable of type `ET_EXEC` with `.p_vaddr == 0`, like so:

```
echo "int main() { return 0; }" | gcc -xc - -o a.out -Wl,-Ttext=0
readelf -l a.out | grep LOAD | head -1
  LOAD           0x0000000000200000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
```

The kernel will refuse to run it:

```
./a.out
Killed
```

Comment: @EmployedRussian: "No. When the kernel discovers that the .p_vaddr == 0 for the first load segment of the executable, it will relocate it elsewhere." Does it? AFAIK, it relocated when the type of the ELF file is `ET_DYN` (at least this is what is expected from the ELF spec).

Comment: @ysdx The `PIE` binary that we are talking about *is* `ET_DYN`, as already discussed in the answer.

Comment: @EmployedRussian, OK, then won't it relocate in all cases?

Comment: @ysdx I don't understand your question. This comment thread is also likely not the place to ask additional questions. If you have one, ask it *as a question* ?

Comment: @EmployedRussian, I mean I would have said "When the type is ET_DYN, it will relocate the segments" instead.

Comment: @ysdx I see. Thanks for suggestion. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) with `MAP_FIXED` a segment starting at `(void*)0` but I don't think you should.

I have no idea if changing the virtual address in [elf(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html) would do the equivalent. Are you speaking of `p_vaddr` for some segment?

Actually, you should really not use the `NULL` address in application code on Linux, especially if some of that code is coded in C, because the `NULL` pointer has a very special meaning, including to the compiler. In particular, some optimizations are done based on the fact that `NULL` is not dereferencable.

It is well known that GCC does optimize, for instance,

```
 x = *p;
 if (!p) goto wasnull;
```

into just `x= *p;` because if `p`has been dereferenced it cannot be `NULL`; And GCC is right in doing that optimization for application code (not for free-standing one).

Also the kernel is usually doing [Address Space Layout Randomization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization).